# Using the recursive model attribute in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, relationships

I'm using CakePHP 2.0 and MySQL. I have the following tables:

```
Stores
-id
-name
-suburb_id

Outlets
-id
-name
-suburb_id

Suburbs
-id
-name
-state_id

States
-id
-code
-name
```

States hasMany Suburbs and Suburbs hasMany stores. When I perform the following find:

```
$this->Outlet->recursive = 0;
$stores = $this->Store->find("all", array('limit' => 50));
```

It retrieves the Outlet, Suburb, Store and State data arrays.

```
[Outlet] => Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [name] => SMOKEYS KEBABS PIZZA /PIDE
    [suburb_id] => 1212
)
[Suburb] => Array
(
    [id] => 1212
    [state_id] => 1
    [name] => Wiangaree
    [State] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [code] => ACT
        [name] => Australian Capital Territory
    )
    [Store] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12814
            [name] => Wiangaree General Store
            [suburb_id] => 1212
        )
    )
)
```

Is there anyway to control what it retrieves? Essentially, I would like the Outlets, related Suburb data and related state data.

Or am I going about this incorrectly? The other option I thought of would be implemented ad hoc joins.

Comment: are you in the Outlet or Store model? because you seem to use/access both... which you shoudnt

Comment: I'm writing a console script inside app/vendors/shells. It uses Store and Outlet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with related models, say `modelA` and `modelB`, if you want to use `find()` with `modelA`, you should set the `recursive` property in that model, not in `modelB`.

Thus in your code you should set it like this:

```
$this->Store->recursive = 0;
$stores = $this->Store->find("all", array('limit' => 50));
```

You can also have more control over what is retrieved using the [`Containable` behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) or the [`fields` option](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find) of the `find()`method.